# Routing on event

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to route to a specific page when the user clicks on a menu option. I already have created a method with the corresponding event but I don't know how to route to the specifc page that was clicked on the menu.

```
menuEvent(event: any): any {
    if (event.item.label == 'First Page') {
         // redirect to 'first-view'
    }
  }
```

The routes are already defined at the `app-routing` module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'first-view'
  },
  {
    path: 'first-view',
    component: FirstViewComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'second-view',
    component: SecondViewComponent
  },
}
```

This seems to be something pretty straightforward but I am new to angular and so have not yet been able to wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject to the component the router

```
 import { Router } from '@angular/router';
 //...
 constructor(private router: Router){...}
```

Then you can do

```
 this.router.navigate(['a', 'b', 'c']);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
this.router.navigate(['/first-view']);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router) { }

menuEvent(event: any): any {
    if (event.item.label == 'First Page') {
        this.router.navigate(['./first-view']);
    }
}
```